# developing in simulator but xcode ask for registered device

Tags: ios, xcode

hi im new to programming

I want to build the app in Xcode as a free user and using simulator only but then got the error "failed to create a provisioning profile. there are no devices registered in your account on the developer website" in signing option.

I tried to register a device on https://developer.apple.com
but they say I need to enroll for developer program to do it, and it needs me to pay with money which I don't want to for this moment.

i've changed the generic device in drop down menu to many simulator but to no avail.

thank you for helping

Comment: Select simulator in spite of generic device in target area.

Comment: Xcode Version ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not require provisioning profile to run application in simulator. And if you have apple account then you can test your application in device. Just add your account in account section in preferences. Xcode will automatically create provisioning certificate to run on you device. Device must have logged in with same apple account.

Comment: yes i know thats why i asked in the first place. already changed the generic device to simulator but keep asking me for provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

> Select simulator instead of the generic device.

Please refer below screenshots.

[image: Generic device]

[image: Simulater]

Run+Build your project.

Comment: already done that, but it keep asking me for provisioning profile.
tried different simulator but xcode still didn't accept it

Answer (score 0):

The way to run iOS applications without having a Provisioning Profile,
as of 07/23/2021 is to remove the Entitlements association, also set your Signing Identity to Automatic.